# how to get file from a passworded area using PHP

Tags: php, file, getfiles

I want to make a script that takes a URL to a file and will import that file to a specific folder in my web server 
how to request a file if it's in a passworded area, i have an account "username/password" but how can i make the request to that file ?

Comment: What kind of username/password does that site have from where you want to pull the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is HTTP Authorization you can access it like that:

`http://username:password@server.com/folder/myfile.jpg`

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the mechanism used to perform the authentication. It might be a formed based system that issues a cookie (in which case you need to make a request to the auth URI and store the returned cookie), it might be HTTP basic authentication (in which case use [CURLOPT_USERPWD](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)).